How do you fix your Swiper slider to respond to its parent element width?
In my react app theres a flex container containing a main and an aside section.
<div className="flex gap-10">
 <div className="flex-1">
//slider content
</div>
 <div className="w-[300px]">
//aside content
</div>
</div>

inside the flex-1 container i've placed my slider content.(below code)
<div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
// marked element A
 <div className="w-full">
      <Swiper
        navigation={{
          prevEl: ".button-prev-slide",
          nextEl: ".button-next-slide",
          disabledClass: "opacity-50"
        }}
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper2 relative"
      >
        {images.map((item, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <img src={item} alt="product images" />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
        <div className="button-prev-slide absolute left-0 top-[50%] z-10 mx-2 flex size-8 -translate-y-1/2 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-white text-black cursor-pointer">
          <MdArrowBack size={20} />
        </div>
        <div className="button-next-slide absolute right-0 top-[50%] z-10 mx-2 flex size-8 -translate-y-1/2 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-white text-black cursor-pointer">
          <MdArrowForward size={20} />
        </div>
      </Swiper>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        watchSlidesProgress={true}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        {images.map((item, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <img src={item} alt="product images" />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
 </div>

...other elements
    </div>

when the marked element A's width is 100% the swiper content sets doesn't aknowledge the width of its parent. but when i set a fixed width like '600px' it does. why is that? and how to fix it.

I don’t understand your objective. Can you reproduce it on a Stack Snippet? Is this something like a Swiper centered slider?

no. did you see the first snippet? there's flex container, inside that container there's the 2nd snippet

Might have something to do with flexbox, and how that first item is allowed to dynamically grow as needed - making it somehow not able to properly determine the necessary width? What happens, when you remove flex-1, and instead set width: calc(100% - 310px) for that element?

@C3roe flex container and all the other elements works fine when the swiper is removed from the dom. issue occurs when i dont assign a width to the swiper wrapper. if its a fixed width (like 600px) it works fine. but when its 100% it breaks

You're only repeating what we already know. And I didn't say anything about the flex columns themselves not working properly.

oh my bad just realized what you suggested earlier it does work! sorry for the misunderstanding
